# Run R Script - Ubuntu Server

Tags: r, ubuntu, ubuntu-16.04

I've recently compiled R on Ubuntu Server 16.04. I'm attempting to run an R Script using the Rscript function, but I'm running into errors.

When I run the script using `Rscript`, the output shows the functions `as()` and `new()` from the methods package included in the R distribution cannot be found. When I run R interactively, I'm able to use these functions without any problem.

Any help would be tremendously appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is a design bug in `Rscript`: it does **not** load `methods` on startup.

Two fixes:

1. Add `library(methods)` to your script, or
2. Do `sudo apt-get install r-cran-littler` and use `r` instead of `Rscript`.

`r` has been loading `methods` since day one as this behaviour of `Rscript` never really made sense.